# How do I make the object(ViewList.SelectedItems) provided as a parameter to Command executed in response to an event?

Tags: c#, xaml, events, parameters, mvvm-light

This seems so fundamental that I feel I must be missing something in my search for a solution.

I have a **ViewModel** that has a **ObservableCollection**< ExcelField>  property which is used as a **ItemsSource** for a **ListView** in the associated **View**.

I have added a **EventToCommand** item in the **View** which accesses a **RelayCommand** to pass the **Command** to a method(ExcelListChanged) in the **ViewModel** with a parameter which is set to the **SelectedItems** property in the **ViewList**.

In my **ViewModel** would like to construct another **List** containing the items that have been selected. In the debugger I am able to examine the contents of the **object** parameter and validate that it indeed holds the information I would like to access. Unfortunately I have not been able to find the key that enables me to access the data in the parameter **object**, I have tried casting, assigning, ChangeTo and more. The cast and ChangeTo exception with a unknown conversion or something similar. I thought since the object is a **ListView.SelectedItems**(?) that I might be able to cast it to some flavor of that but it appears that is not doable outside of a ListView object.

A simple solution would be great, a complicated one would be okay and a convoluted one painful.

Thanks for any guidance.

Here are the code pieces

The data structure

```
public struct ExcelField
{
    private int index;
    public int Index
    {
        get { return index; }
        private set { index = value; }
    }
    private string fieldName;
    public string FieldName
    {
        get { return fieldName; }
        private set { fieldName = value;  }
    }

    public ExcelField(int ndx, string name)
    {
        index = ndx;
        fieldName = name;
    }
}
```

Pieces from the ViewModel

```
    ObservableCollection<ExcelField> fieldNames;
    public ObservableCollection<ExcelField> FieldNames
    {
        get
        {
            return fieldNames;
        }
        set
        {
            fieldNames = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("FieldNames");
        }
    }
```

```cs
       allListChanged = new RelayCommand(args => ExcelListChanged(args));
```

```cs
    RelayCommand allListChanged;
    public RelayCommand AllListChanged
    {
        get
        {
            return allListChanged;
        }
    }
```

```cs
    private void ExcelListChanged(object parameter)
    {
        var whata = parameter.GetType();
        return;
    }
```

And finally the View pieces

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ViewModel:ExcelMapperViewModel x:Key="ExcelMapperViewModelDataSource" d:IsDataSource="True"/>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ExcelFieldTemplate">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding FieldName, Mode=OneWay}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Index, Mode=OneWay}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>


    <ListView x:Name="AllFields" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="3"
        ItemsSource="{Binding FieldNames}"
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ExcelFieldTemplate}"
        >
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}" />
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Index}" Header="Index"/>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FieldName}" Header="Field Name"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                <Custom:EventToCommand
                    Command="{Binding AllListChanged, Mode=OneWay}"
                    CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=AllFields, Path=SelectedItems}"
                />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </ListView>
```

I set a breakpoint on ExcelListChanged and run the code. When I select items in the ListView ExcelListChanged is triggered and I can examine the parameter *object*. I am able to see the number of entries selected as a Count on parameter and a array of ExcelField items with the appropriate information for the fields within the structure.

So how do I access the information I can see in the debugger programmatically?

Comment: Include the relevant code for what you have tried and where the problem is occurring

Answer (score 0):

since SelectedItems is an IList http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ilist(v=vs.110).aspx
you can simply iterate through it...

```
   private void ExcelListChanged(object parameter)
{
    IList iConverted= parameter as IList;
    if(iConverted!=null){
      foreach(YouKnowTheTypeOfElements theElement in iConverted) {
         doSomethingWith(theElement);
      }
    }
    return;
}
```